# @ApiModelProperty with dataType java.time.LocalDate not resolvable

Tags: java, swagger-2.0, springfox

We have a Spring Boot 2 application with Springfox 2.9.2 to describe the API and we have marked our API with Swagger annotations @ApiModelProperty. We have something like this in our API:

```
@ApiModelProperty(value = "mumbo-jumbo", dataType = "java.time.LocalDate", example = "2018-03-20")
private String paymentAccountAge;
```

We have configured Swagger2 via Springfox as follows:

```
return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    ...
    .alternateTypeRules(
       ...
       newRule(typeResolver.resolve(LocalDate.class), typeResolver.resolve(String.class)),
       ...)
```

However the Swagger Documentation Page is producing errors:

```
Errors
Hide
Resolver error at paths./startAuth.post.parameters.1.schema.properties.accountInfo.properties.paymentAccountAge.$ref
Could not resolve reference because of: Could not resolve pointer: /definitions/LocalDate does not exist in document
```

Any idea why Swagger2 ist not working properly?

Comment: [Does swagger2 have any support for java.time introduced in java8](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/914)

Comment: @Andreas, your reference is quite old, i.e. from 2015. Furthermore, they suggest to state the dataType as a full qualified class name which is the case here: java.time.LocalDate

Comment: What version of `springfox` you are using?

Comment: @SSK As you can see above version 2.9.2.

Comment: I think `2.9.2` does not support `LocalDate` try using latest `3.0.0`

Comment: Springfox 3.0.0 still does not support java.time.LocalDate or java.time.ZonedDateTime - just tested.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `dataType = "java.time.LocalDate"`.
It works for me.

```
@ApiModelProperty(value = "mumbo-jumbo", example = "2018-03-20")
private String paymentAccountAge;
```